# how to get current request's url in pywebio

Tags: python, web, url, tornado

I am using pywebio framework. I want get current request's url in pywebio.

I've tried using pywebio.session.info but no success.

please help me, thanks.

Comment: Does this work: `pywebio.session.request.uri`, or try `pywebio.session.request.path`.

Comment: no, I get this "AttributeError: module 'pywebio.session' has no attribute 'request'"

Comment: What about `pywebio.session.info.request.uri`?

Comment: Ive tried but it doesnt give me the url, im trying to make google oauth so i need the code from the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `eval_js` to run a JS code and get the url, e.g.:

```
from pywebio.session import eval_js

url = eval_js('window.location.href')
```

Doc: https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/session.html?highlight=eval_js#pywebio.session.eval_js